# Problema com acentuação em formulário de e-mail

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário, email, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou com um formulário de e-mail em PHP que não envia corretamente palavras acentuadas, aparecem várias interrogações em palavras com acento, cedilha etc. Tentei várias coisas mas nenhuma deu certo.

Segue abaixo o script que estou usando. Ele está rodando em um modelo de página do Wordpress.

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
//Check to see if the honeypot captcha field was filled in
if(trim($_POST['checking']) !== '') {
    $captchaError = true;
} else {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError = 'Informe seu nome.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['emaill']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Informe se endereço de e-mail.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['emaill']))) {
        $emailError = 'Informe um endereço de e-mail válido.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $emaill = trim($_POST['emaill']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'Escreva sua mensagem.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email

    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'email@site.com';
        $subject = '[Contato] '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $emaill \n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $emaill; 
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        if($sendCopy == true) {
            $subject = 'You emailed Your Name';
            $headers = 'From: Tanmay <email@site.com>';
            mail($emaill, $subject, $body, $headers);
        }

        $emailSent = true;

    }
}
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa é bem simples, só esta faltando setar a codificação para: UTF-8

```
$mail->CharSet = "utf8";
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o seguinte código:

```
$headers    = array
    (
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
        'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
        'Message-ID: <' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        'X-Mailer: PHP v' . phpversion(),
        'X-Originating-IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'],
    );
```

Fonte: [Manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Lembrando que para que a mensagem não seja bloqueada precisa colocar no from e no Return-path um e-mail válido de seu domínio.
Hoje, todos os servidores Linux da Locaweb usam Postfix, e caso você não especifique o From na hora de enviar a mensagem, ele forja o from email@host.com.br (o host seria o nome do servidor onde seu site está hospedado), e isso é bloqueado.Ou seja, sua mensagem não será enviada

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -2):

Outra boa dica é você passar seu texto para um Entities Encoder como este: https://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder.

ou no seu método de enviar email codifique a mensagem com html entities do PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php

Sucesso em sua jornada!